# How can i use custom attribute my c# project

Tags: c#, validation, caching, logging, fluent

i want use  custom attribute on my n-tier project. for

-Caching-
-Logging
-Validation
-Exception

Comment: Okay, but there is no question. What have you tried? What is happening or not happening? Any code?

Comment: i  already asked a question on my caption. "How can i use custom attribute my c# project"

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should search for AOP. this is some kind of developing methodology

> Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) is a programming paradigm that aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns. *Wikipedia*

It is not as simple as you think,in C# you have to use some 3rd party Library.

I suggest to start with [MrAdvice](https://github.com/ArxOne/MrAdvice), it will helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Alright is this 3.rd  party  best way for the aop ?

What is the best and simple alternative postsharp ?

Comment: is this 3.rd party best way for the aop ? No and Yes.  What is the best and simple alternative postsharp ? It depends, i think it is a good start, and it is free

Answer (score 0):

Writing your custom attributes would look a little something like this:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class LogAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool _loggingEnabled;

    public LogAttribute(loggingEnabled)
    {
        _loggingEnabled = loggingEnabled;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
[Log(true)]
public class SampleClass
{
}
```

If you require further clarification if you share a little bit more about your intended usage of the attributes I'd be able to clarify a bit more. For instance, I'm not sure if you wanted your logging attribute to give you a means to explicitly state if that class/struct would be logged, but that's how I decided to demonstrate this. Also, note you can apply that to properties, and various other members via the `AttributeUsage` attribute on your attribute class declaration. I hope that helps.

Update:

Save method example:

```
[Log(true)]
public void Save(Company company)
{
   _context.Save();
}
```

Then you'll use the static method `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType)` to retrieve information stored in that attribute. Since in this case, you'll likely want to use logging in many places you'd write another method (most likely static as well) somewhere else in your application that'd look something like this (see the link to the System.Reflection reference below for more information).

```
public static void Log(MemberInfo element)
{
     LogAttribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(element, typeof(LogAttribute);

     if (attribute._loggingEnabled)
     {
         // Create log file and add information from here.
     }
}
```

[Attribute Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes)

[Reflection Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/retrieving-information-stored-in-attributes)

Comment: Can not trigger this method.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your comment? I've read it over a few times and I still don't understand what you mean by not being able to trigger a method. My best guess is you're trying to write an attribute to trigger a custom action on a method that was not at all mentioned in the question but again that's my best guess. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: If that is the case let me know and I can edit with an example for that as well. If that's not it please elaborate more and I should still be able to help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My mistake.. Sorry. 

I want to make custom attribute for the for the AOP process. 

manuel or 3. pary how can i . do it ?

Example:I want to: Run my attribute before or after for the business method.


Like this

[Log()]

public void Save(Company company)

{
return _context.Save();
}

Comment: Oh good, I'm glad that helped. I'll add what I think you're asking for with the Save method there to my answer. It should only take a few minutes.